# How I'm going to award a bounty if there are no answers?

Tags: support, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669399/how-to-process-partial-payment-in-point-of-sale-in-odoo10) has not been answered, and the countdown of my bounty has finished.

Now I think I'm going to lose my points and anyone has answered the question!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) should answer your question. Regarding the question in question: I have no idea about Odoo10, but your question seems to lack some explanation on what you exactly want to achieve. The better you describe the problem, the more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: The question is asked by another person, and I've found the link because I was searching the exactly same problem. I fully understand the question besides I am not the author :D

Comment: Wow seems pretty unfair to not return the points if zero answers are given. I understand to take the points if someone has answered and you didn't like the explanation, but in this case the question is completely desert...

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you with the OP of the SO question, I edited your Meta question again. Regarding the "unfairness": You have to view a bounty like an advertisement. It simply doesn't guarantee any effect.

Comment: @Dev_NIX: If you advertise on a website, you don't get a refund either, if you're not selling your product.

Comment: this question seems to fit under the "we're not the support of ${yourFavoriteProduct}". Even if it is not you may ask to the Odoo people themselves to get a proper answer.

Comment: @Walfrat  I don't think this is a customer support issue. The way I read it that question, it's about how to configure an option. That can be answered by others than the Odoo developers.

Answer (score 2):

From the [help center](/help/bounty):

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.

So sadly, you'll lose your reputation (in fact, you've already lost them when placing the bounty).

---

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to *answers*.

That means there was no way for you to award your bounty, not even to the asker of the question.