# I am asked to award a bounty, despite there is no answer

Tags: support, bug, bounty

I am new to bounties, and I read 
[What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
and 
[How I'm going to award a bounty if there are no answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346248/1851270)

I still do not understand why, despite I have no answers, I have a the following inbox message:

> Your bounty on question "R: download data securely using TLS/SSL" is completed. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.

Isn't the bot supposed to know there is no answer (and none can arrive, since time has expired)? What am I missing?

Comment: _"and none can arrive, since time has expired"_ Huh? Your question can still receive answers, even if the bouty has expired. But yes, obviously the bot doesn't take in account your question did't receive an answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. It's just a custom notification which appears right after the bounty period ends and the bounty isn't awarded to any answer yet. It looks, like you've found UI inconsistency.

Normally, after 24 hours, half of the prize will be awarded to the answer picked up according to the algorithm which is described in one of the sources you have provided.

Comment: and the othe half? is it lost/vanished? -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty